# update specific cell value when specific cell value is changed

Tags: excel, vba

Iam very new to exel vba studing vba my own. I have a two cell ranges that is range(j11:j100") and  range("o11:o100")
both carrying date format only. suppose if i change a date in range("J11") to 1-1-2022 then automatically
date in the  corresponding range("O11") should  update by adding 28 days to it which will be 29-1-2022 which works fine with below code but if i change
date in range("j12") to 2-1-2022 then the corresponding range("O12") should update by adding 28 day to it which should be 30-1-2022, but instead
it updates to 29-1-2022

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim rColumn As Range
  Dim tTable As Range
  Set rColumn = Me.Range("j11:J15")
   Set tTable = Me.Range("O11:O15")
   If Not Intersect(Target, rColumn) Is Nothing Then
         If Target.Count = 1 Then
    Intersect(Target.EntireRow, tTable) = Range("J11") + 28
      End If
     End If
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J11:J15")) Is Nothing Then
  End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: You need to check date formats.

Comment: Date format is dd-mm-yyyy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're always adding 28 days to the value in `Range("J11")` instead of changed cell, so change the 8th line to:

```
Intersect(Target.EntireRow, tTable) = Target + 28
```

Comment: 8th line  code was changed as you said. Its working. 
Thank you for your valuable suggestion